# vscode run commands on remote linux from editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am new to vscode and able to connect to remove rocky linux vm using remote ssh extension.
Create a file on remote.
I do get the shell.
how do I run the commands that I write in the file.
similar to powershell ISE, highlight the line and execute it.
Is it even possible?
[image: img1]

Comment: on the terminal you source the script file: `. script.sh` or `source script.sh`

Comment: I get that, but I want to write the commands or script and run specific blocks. will that be possible? from the top pane, not from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

With the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#interminal) you can construct the text to send to the terminal based on the selection

All key bindings use the **same** key combo

You need to define them in **this** order in the file `keybindings.json`

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i f5",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
    "args": {
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": { "text": "${selectedText}" },
      "addCR": true
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i f5",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
    "args": {
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": { "text": "${selectedText}" },
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && extraContext:editorSelectionEndCharacter == '1'"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i f5",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
    "args": {
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.currentLineText",
      "addCR": true
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
  }
```

The second key binding uses the extension [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context) v0.5.0

Comment: @wasim please update the key bindings, there was a "typo" in binding 2